# How to pass string with space in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, string, razor

I am trying to set an image source with razor, like this :

```
<img src=@myStringWithSpace>
```

The problem is, sometimes there is space in myStringWithSpace. eg :

```
@Code Dim myStringWithSpace= "Alpha Romeo.jpg" EndCode
```

When the html is rendered I get

```
<img src="Alpha" Romeo.jpg>
```

I wonder how can I get

```
<img src="Alpha Romeo.jpg">
```

Comment: What's wrong with `<img src="@myStringWithSpace">`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `@`prefix.

Space is not a problem. Space will be converted to `%20` You do not need to worry about it. You just need to make sure that you are enclosing the value of your string in single or double quotes.

```
<img src="@myStringWithSpace" alt="some alt text" />
```

or

```
<img src='@myStringWithSpace' alt="some alt text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the following (Note: This is in C#, but the idea is the same):

```
@{
   string bold = string.Empty;
   bold = "style='font-weight:bold; border-top:1px solid black;'";
}

<div @bold> ... </div>
```

but to work, I had to change it to:

```
@{
   string bold = string.Empty;
   bold = "font-weight:bold; border-top:1px solid black;";
}

<div style="@bold"> ... </div>
```

Basically, instead of including the HTML keyword into the string, just write the value and then insert the string into the HTML inside the quotes.